# What makes electrons land so strictly scattered after passing through a hole, slit or double slit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, electrons, diffraction

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv12oB_uyFs) you can see electrons landing on a receptor and building up an interference pattern after passing through a (nano-size) double slit screen. I have read about diffraction and interacting electric fields scattering waves/particles pretty randomly. Still, it strikes me as if the waves collapsing into final impact points on the receptor are carefully exhausting the landing-spot possibilities before beginning to accumulate into denser patterns. Is this simply the laws of averages and possibilities doing their part or maybe the waves "know" not to collapse into impact points exactly where others already have?

Comment: Perhaps it is helpful to read [about electron deflection in a historical overview](https://www.academia.edu/27983554/Deflection_of_electron_beams_at_edges). If it is something unclear after reading I can give an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the very interesting paper. It should be obvious to me that the following  paragraph should answer my question: "The deflection of the electrons is effected by the interaction between the surface electrons of an edge and the electron beam. Through a quantized field between an edge and the electron beam it comes to a periodical bundling of the electrons and to an intensity distribution on the observation screen."

Comment: Still, I find it puzzling the way single electrons distribute at the observation screen, very rarely overlapping even as the patterns become denser. Magnificently orderly random, is my feeling.

Comment: &WaltherMPL from your first comment, I'm very happy you extract the main idea.    The overlapping happens due to the different starting points and different -even if small - velocities of the flying electrons as well as the vibrations of the surface electrons.

Comment: Walther, if you understand German, there is an original German version too.

Comment: I don't speak German, sadly, but I think I can understand now. In fact, given the many variables between electrons as you mention, it would be puzzling to actually see them NOT scattering as they do! Thanks a bunch for your help.